# Vue/Vuetify says Icon value is undefined or null

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, material-design-icons, vuetifyjs3

I load a list of items from the db which are to be displayed to the user in a list. Each item is of a particular **type**, and depending on the type, I wish to show an icon next to it.

I've created a component to control the icon that will be shown. The component accepts the **type** sa a prop and renders the mdi-icon accordingly.

```
<div v-if="iconName !== ''">
  <v-icon large color="blue-grey darken-2"> 
    {{ iconName }}
  </v-icon> 
  </div>
```

The value of iconName is provided either while mounting, or as a computed property - I tried both of these.

```
export default {
  props: ["activityType"],

  data() {
    return {
      iconType: this.activityType, 
      iconName: 'mdi-script-text-outline', 
      iconMapping: {
        learning_material_video: "mdi-video",
        learning_material_quiz: "mdi-head-question-outline",
        learning_material_article: "mdi-script-text-outline",
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {},
  mounted(){
    this.iconName = this.iconMapping[this.iconType]
  },
  computed: {
    // iconName() {
    //   return this.iconMapping[this.activityType]
    // },
  },
};
```

This renders perfectly fine and I can ignore and continue working on the next component but the error in the console is a bit worrysome.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Icon value is undefined or null
at ReactiveEffect.eval [as fn] (icons.tsx?ff78:168:1)
at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:167:1)
at ComputedRefImpl.get value [as value] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1101:1)
at Proxy.eval (VIcon.tsx?e5c2:53:1)
at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:893:1)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5098:1)
at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:167:1)
at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:155:1)
at flushJobs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:394:1)
at flushJobs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:409:1)
```

This has no effect in how the page looks or works but I'm worried if this might create issues later. I'm hardly 5 days in into Vue and I might be doing something wrong here. Is my code the right way to do it or can it be better?

ps. This is Vuetify-3.

Comment: You can try adding `v-if="iconName"` to your `v-icon`.

Comment: @IVOGELOV edited the question to show you what I'm already doing. If I add v-if to v-icon instead, the first icon doesn't load (but rest of them do).

Comment: @Aditya you used ```v-if="iconName !== ''"``` in your code, but if I am not wrong the ```iconName``` has default value and that condition does not solve the problem. You should post the codes of **parent** component that loads data to get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a safety guard:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-icon large color="blue-grey darken-2">{{ iconName }}</v-icon> 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  name: 'MyCustomComponent',
  props:
  {
    activityType:
    {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  computed
  {
    iconName()
    {
      return {
        learning_material_video: "mdi-video",
        learning_material_quiz: "mdi-head-question-outline",
        learning_material_article: "mdi-script-text-outline",
      }[this.activityType] || 'mdi-script-text-outline';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I load a list of items from the db

I think the issue is somewhere there. The error you're getting basically says that when you fetch the data, something goes wrong but you don't [catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) it (don't do anything about it). I think in your case you need to catch the error and assign a value to `Icon` inside the `catch` block.